# I am trying to use local service(.svc) in web.config endpoints but I got an error in SettingServiceCLient.cs functions

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, tfs

I am new in TFS and WCF, 
I hope someone can help me.

This is the error message

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> One or more errors occurred.  Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please
>   review the stack trace for more information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail,
>   System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]: One or more errors occurred.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 37:  Line 38:         public List
>   GetCompanyCarrierSettings(string companyId) { Line 39:
>   return Channel.GetCompanyCarrierSettings(companyId); Line 40:
>   } Line 41:
>
> Source File: C:\Users\63917\Desktop\Custom - RW source\Customs -
>   Integrated
>   Dashboard\IntegrationDashboard\CCN.IntegrationDashboard.Web\Proxies\SettingServiceClient.cs
>   Line: 39

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there something wrong with the client invocation, which is commonly achieved by a client proxy. The error typically indicates the destination URL service does not work properly. Is the service address right? It should be the base address of the WCF service. We could verify it by accessing the service creation page on the client-side.

```
 Http://vabqia969vm:21011/service1.svc
```

If the page is working properly, we should check if the client service URL is right.
Here is an example of calling WCF service by using a WCF client.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/accessing-services-using-a-wcf-client
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.